# Getting the final rendered height of a static page in a WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

In my app I’m using a `WKWebView` which loads webpages with static content.

I want to know the height of the `contentSize` as soon as the webpage is fully rendered in the `WKWebView`.

So I thought I could use the `webView:didFinishNavigation:` delegate for that:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.uiDelegate = self

        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.rockade.nl/testpage/testpage.php")!))
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("finished loading: height=\(webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)")
    }

}
```

My problem with this code is that this delegate is called *before* the page is fully rendered, so I’m getting different results for the height, even values of 0.

When I add a small delay I’m getting the correct results, but that feels like a hack.

Using a observer like this

```
var myContext = 0
webView.scrollView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: &myContext)

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if context == &myContext {
            print(webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)
        } else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
        }
    }
}
```

doesn’t help me too, because I really need to be sure that a received value is the final height.

Good to know: I don’t have control over the webpages, so using javascript is not an option.

I hope someone can point me into the right direction!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So you don't have control over webpages but html dom is not changes on page to page. So you can use script to get the height of your page.

Maybe this helps to you:

```
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
            if complete != nil {
                webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
                    // Here is your height
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

PS: You can try 'document.body.offsetHeight' instead of scroll height also.

Comment: Great, this solves my problem! I don't even need to get the scrollHeight or offsetHeight with evaluateJavascript in the completion handler, since I can get the correct height with webView.scrollView.contentSize.height there.

Comment: Well, nice to hear that :)

Comment: This is good solution, but it does not give the correct height of the final rendered page in all cases. If the connection is slow this will execute before the contents are loaded on the page.

Comment: In fact this will execute always when the WKWebView finishes navigation, but that will not mean you have all the contents loaded on screen

Answer (score 0):

For me this was an improvement in terms of getting a larger more appropriate number, but I'm still not sure it's completely right.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState") { [weak self] (complete, error) in
            if complete != nil {
                self?.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight"){ [weak self] (result, error) in
                    if let height = result as? CGFloat {
                        self?.updateHeight(height + 80)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```