# Get content Height of WKWebView incorrect

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm facing the issue with getting content Height of WebView by Whooshkaa playlist link https://player.whooshkaa.com/player/playlist/show/2321?sharing=true.

The WKWebView inside custom View and I'm gonna recalculate frame view after loading WebView success.

I've tried 3 ways:

- Create an observer when the webView contentSize changed like this [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295762/detect-changes-to-uiwebviews-scroll-views-contentsize?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).
- EvaluateJavaScript like this:

```swift
  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.offsetHeight") { [weak self] (height, _) in
        guard let height = height as? CGFloat else { return }
        // Still 200
    }
}
```

**---> But all the cases return offsetHeight only 200px.** 
As you can see it's still missing the playlist content bellow.

[image]

Is there another way/trick that I can get offsetHeight correctly?

Comment: see this for e.g : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515236/how-to-determine-the-content-size-of-a-wkwebview

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578817/getting-the-final-rendered-height-of-a-static-page-in-a-wkwebview/50579149#50579149

Comment: 200px seem like the correct number, are you sure you are updating webview height?

Comment: @ymutlu It's not correct, pls take a look at the image I posted, and open the link as well. You can see the mismatch between those.

Comment: I have added image as answer, please check.

Answer (score 1):

200px is min height for the page you have shared. You might need to check your webview frame.

Do not use CGRect.zero for the initial frame, this might cause error loading page. I have added simple code example and it works as it should.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your answer seems like I have to minus the webView frame?
I create the WebView with WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero).
My goal is I need to set the frame of webView based on the webView's content size after loading finish.